# Error: "El proveedor 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' no está registrado en el equipo local"

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, microsoft-office

Intento conectar a una base de datos Access 2016 con Visual Studio 2019 en Visual Basic. Tengo Office 2016 de 32 bits y Windows 10 64 bits. Ya he instalado los drivers de 32 bits para la conexión con la base de datos y me sigue saltando la excepción al conectar. ¿Podría alguien ayudarme? Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio ¿Podrías por favor  agregar que estas realizando?. , revisa [ask], saludos

Comment: Descarga el Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias. Ya lo he solucionado. Después de bajarme los drivers del Access Database Engine de 2016, cambié la plataforma en opciones de compilación a x86 y solucionado. Un saludo!